# Assigning POSIX times to unequal intervals in R

Tags: r, posix, intervals

I have a list of incoming times:

```
dim(incoming)
[1] 50357     1
```

```
head(incoming, n = 50)
 [1] "2015-10-08 02:14:46 EST" "2015-10-08 16:18:04 EST" "2015-10-08 01:32:42 EST" "2015-10-08 18:48:40 EST"
 [5] "2015-10-08 16:53:33 EST" "2015-10-08 12:23:37 EST" "2015-10-08 06:38:34 EST" "2015-10-08 17:15:41 EST"
 [9] "2015-10-08 19:43:00 EST" "2015-10-08 18:19:44 EST" "2015-10-08 01:10:39 EST" "2015-10-08 19:45:04 EST"
[13] "2015-10-08 18:29:57 EST" "2015-10-08 10:11:58 EST" "2015-10-08 08:44:10 EST" "2015-10-08 09:32:25 EST"
[17] "2015-10-08 08:23:32 EST" "2015-10-08 14:11:49 EST" "2015-10-08 06:27:45 EST" "2015-10-08 00:54:38 EST"
[21] "2015-10-08 08:56:34 EST" "2015-10-08 07:12:52 EST" "2015-10-08 18:28:40 EST" "2015-10-08 09:35:34 EST"
[25] "2015-10-08 09:51:06 EST" "2015-10-08 08:53:54 EST" "2015-10-08 00:42:43 EST" "2015-10-08 10:25:04 EST"
[29] "2015-10-08 07:13:28 EST" "2015-10-08 08:09:18 EST" "2015-10-08 16:32:59 EST" "2015-10-08 07:37:25 EST"
[33] "2015-10-08 07:46:52 EST" "2015-10-08 08:25:11 EST" "2015-10-08 11:51:10 EST" "2015-10-08 02:02:02 EST"
[37] "2015-10-08 09:23:24 EST" "2015-10-08 12:03:03 EST" "2015-10-08 07:36:34 EST" "2015-10-08 08:27:38 EST"
[41] "2015-10-08 02:16:47 EST" "2015-10-08 08:11:54 EST" "2015-10-08 07:46:22 EST" "2015-10-08 08:34:52 EST"
[45] "2015-10-08 00:00:37 EST" "2015-10-08 08:37:26 EST" "2015-10-08 01:33:00 EST" "2015-10-08 17:16:15 EST"
[49] "2015-10-08 09:10:07 EST" "2015-10-08 08:07:43 EST"
```

My objective is to assign these times to the corresponding interval they they fall under, however, these intervals are not equally spaced apart.  For example: the first 25 intervals are:

```
head(data, n = 25)
              interval
1  2015-10-08 00:05:00
2  2015-10-08 00:12:00
3  2015-10-08 00:34:00
4  2015-10-08 00:40:00
5  2015-10-08 01:32:00
6  2015-10-08 01:52:00
7  2015-10-08 02:52:00
8  2015-10-08 02:58:00
9  2015-10-08 04:13:00
10 2015-10-08 04:30:00
11 2015-10-08 05:58:00
12 2015-10-08 06:16:00
13 2015-10-08 06:41:00
14 2015-10-08 06:54:00
15 2015-10-08 07:07:00
16 2015-10-08 07:25:00
17 2015-10-08 07:38:00
18 2015-10-08 07:52:00
19 2015-10-08 08:05:00
20 2015-10-08 08:18:00
21 2015-10-08 08:31:00
22 2015-10-08 08:44:00
23 2015-10-08 08:57:00
24 2015-10-08 09:10:00
25 2015-10-08 09:22:00
```

For example, the first time `incoming[1,]` should be assigned to the 02:52:00 interval, as it falls between 01:52:00 and 02:52:00,  the third time `incoming[3,]` should be assigned to the 01:52:00 interval, as it falls between 01:32:00 and 01:52:00, and so on.

My ultimate objective is to count how many incoming times fall within each interval.  I am able summarize the incoming times into even sequences such as 10-minute time intervals with: `interval <- incoming - minutes(minute(incoming) %% 10) - seconds(second(incoming))` which would assign each time to a 10-minute interval but am not sure how to do this with uneven intervals

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(interval = structure(c(1444280700, 1444281120, 
1444282440, 1444282800, 1444285920, 1444287120, 1444290720, 1444291080, 
1444295580, 1444296600, 1444301880, 1444302960, 1444304460, 1444305240, 
1444306020, 1444307100, 1444307880, 1444308720, 1444309500, 1444310280, 
1444311060, 1444311840, 1444312620, 1444313400, 1444314120, 1444314900, 
1444315680, 1444316400, 1444317120, 1444317840, 1444318620, 1444319340, 
1444320180, 1444321080, 1444321980, 1444322880, 1444323720, 1444324620, 
1444325520, 1444326420, 1444327140, 1444327920, 1444328640, 1444329420, 
1444330140, 1444330920, 1444331700, 1444332480, 1444333200, 1444333980, 
1444334820, 1444335600, 1444336380, 1444337160, 1444337940, 1444338780, 
1444339560, 1444340340, 1444341120, 1444341960, 1444342740, 1444343520, 
1444344780, 1444345920, 1444346700, 1444347480, 1444348260, 1444349040, 
1444349820, 1444350600, 1444351380, 1444352100, 1444352880, 1444353660, 
1444354740, 1444355580, 1444356180, 1444357080, 1444357740, 1444358460, 
1444359180, 1444359840, 1444360560, 1444361220, 1444361880, 1444362960, 
1444363440, 1444364160, 1444364640, 1444365300, 1444366200, 1444366560
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "EST")), .Names = "interval", row.names = c(NA, 
92L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
> dput(head(incoming, n = 100))
structure(list(incoming = structure(c(1444288486, 1444339084, 
1444285962, 1444348120, 1444341213, 1444325017, 1444304314, 1444342541, 
1444351380, 1444346384, 1444284639, 1444351504, 1444346997, 1444317118, 
1444311850, 1444314745, 1444310612, 1444331509, 1444303665, 1444283678, 
1444312594, 1444306372, 1444346920, 1444314934, 1444315866, 1444312434, 
1444282963, 1444317904, 1444306408, 1444309758, 1444339979, 1444307845, 
1444308412, 1444310711, 1444323070, 1444287722, 1444314204, 1444323783, 
1444307794, 1444310858, 1444288607, 1444309914, 1444308382, 1444311292, 
1444280437, 1444311446, 1444285980, 1444342575, 1444313407, 1444309663, 
1444313328, 1444313004, 1444312594, 1444311171, 1444312992, 1444305160, 
1444305558, 1444310477, 1444301756, 1444308008, 1444310435, 1444311397, 
1444305549, 1444281371, 1444281799, 1444282338, 1444281573, 1444280541, 
1444281215, 1444280953, 1444281107, 1444281161, 1444280640, 1444280639, 
1444281847, 1444327017, 1444281855, 1444281842, 1444280998, 1444280620, 
1444280466, 1444280579, 1444280881, 1444280534, 1444280879, 1444280535, 
1444280610, 1444280449, 1444280413, 1444280574, 1444280482, 1444280543, 
1444280536, 1444280527, 1444280889, 1444281854, 1444280954, 1444280444, 
1444281531, 1444281033), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "EST")), .Names = "incoming", row.names = c(NA, 
100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used scan to read in these times (which resulted in them both being in my timezone) and then checked to see if `findInterval` was the right choice, and it appears to handle POSIXct objects without complaint (since they are after stored as numeric mode):

```
> table( findInterval( incoming$incoming, data$interval) )  # redone with new dput output

 0  1  2  4  5  6 10 12 13 14 15 16 17 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 30 36 37 38 40 46 56 57 59 60 64 65 66 71 
18  8 11  3  2  3  1  2  1  2  2  2  3  3  5  4  4  3  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  2  1  2
```

The zero interval is before the first "cut" in the interval vector. If you wnat it to be shifted by one, then flank the cutpoint vector (second argument) with `-Inf` and `Inf`.

Comment: I am assuming that `interval` in the above solution refers to `data` in my example? In any case when I input that code I receive the following error: `Error in findInterval(incoming, interval) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Comment: Your data is in dataframe form, so (as always) you need to extract columns from it when passing vectors to functions.